# What is the basic functionality difference between a class and a structure?

Tags: c++

In C programming if i will declare a structure with private fields and some public methods, will it behave as a class?

Answer (score 3):

A `class`'s members are `private` by default, and a `struct`'s are `public`:

```
class A {
    int x; // this is private to A
};

struct B {
    int y; // this is public
};
```

Also when it comes to inheritance, a `class` will inherit `private`ly by default and a `struct` will inherit `public`ally:

```
class C : B { }; // private inheritance

struct D : B { }; // public inheritance
```

That's it.